# How to Ping a Network for Testing Connectivity

Tags: ping

I want to check the connectivity between my laptop and mobile phone which use same network

ping networking

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and type `ping <TestIP>`

For example:

```bash
ping 127.0.0.1
```